# Passing value to an existing variable in makefile

Tags: makefile

I found this `port = ${PORT}` in one makefile. How can I pass value to the variable `port` using make commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for many simple situations, pass the values on the command line using the variable=value grammar. Note that this will (usually) override the value in the Makefile.

```
make PORT=1234 ...
# OR
make port=1234 ...
```

This format will also override other variable settings (environment variables, built-in variables, ...). It will NOT replace variables set with the 'override' directive.

@rveerd comment provide a link to more complete answer.

Comment: Note that these are two separate variables. In this particular example `port` gets copied from the uppercase `PORT` within the Makefile as per the code the OP posted, so both will work.